# How do you unnest multiple arrays in a SQLAlchemy query?

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using PostgreSQL 11 and SQLAlchemy. I have the following table mapped to the `PostSignature` class:

```
             Table "public.post_signature"
  Column   |   Type    | Collation | Nullable | Default
-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------
 post_id   | integer   |           | not null |
 signature | bytea     |           | not null |
 words     | integer[] |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "post_signature_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (post_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "post_signature_post_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post(id)
```

For context, I want to sort by creating a 'score' value, which is the count of the number of elements in "words" that match a query parameter. I want the matching to be element-wise, instead of just a set intersection. All arrays have the same element count.

I have found that the following raw SQL query accomplishes this task:

```
SELECT s.post_id, s.signature, count(a.query) AS score 
FROM post_signature AS s, unnest(s.words, $1) AS a(word, query) 
WHERE a.word = a.query 
GROUP BY s.post_id 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 100;
```

I'm looking to write this as a SQLAlchemy statement that would be equivalent to this. Something like: `session.query(PostSignature).<some statement>.limit(100).all()`

Does anyone know how I can construct this query?

Comment: Do you really want a SQLAlchemy solution, or you would be interested in (raw) SQL code?

Comment: @GMB You can provide both, if you wish, but ultimately I would need the SQLAlchemy solution, as that's how I will be running the query. I'm also trying to avoid writing raw SQL within Python wherever possible